# Request for TOKEN but no TOKEN returns

Tags: raspberry-pi, google-assistant-sdk, magic-mirror

I have successfully request for credentials.json for Google-Oauthlib tool by following this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/device-registration/register-device-manual#register-instance
. It's something looks like this.

[Json return image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UH5pQ.png)

According to the tutorial, i find no $ACCESS_TOKEN. Is there a way to claim this? I think there's something to do with the 2 links in "scope" section.
Btw, i'm trying to personalize google assistant, i want to know if there is a way to control webcam, simply say "Hey Google take a picture", it takes a picture then show it on the screen for some seconds.

Thank you for your attention.